# kubectl cp from a completed pod to local computer

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I would like to use kubectl cp to copy a file from a completed pod to my local host(local computer). I used **kubectl cp /:/** , however, it gave me an **error: cannot exec into a container in a completed pod; current phase is Succeeded** error. Is there a way I can copy a file from a completed pod? It does not need to be kubectl cp. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @Turing85 You should copy this down as an answer instead of a comment :)

Comment: @coderanger [done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68759303/4216641).

Answer (score 6):

Nope. If the pod is gone, it's gone for good. Only possibility would be if the data is stored in a [PV](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) or some other external resource. Pods are [cattle, not pets](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-definition-of-cattle-not-pets).

Answer (score 2):

You *can* find the files, because the containers of a pod in the state `Completed` are not deleted, they are just not running.

I am not aware of any way to do it via Kubernetes itself, but here is how to do it if your container runtime is Docker:

```
$ ssh <node where the pod is>
$ docker ps -a | grep <pod name>
$ docker cp <pod name>:/your/files ./
```

The files in containers [are just overlayfs mounts](https://lwn.net/Articles/902049/); if the container still exists, the files still exist.

So if you are using containerd runtime or something else, look at `/var/lib/containers` or something (don't know where different runtimes do their overlayfs mounts, but it can't not be at the node. you could check if you find out where via `$ mount`).